# How to calculate text height on jailbreak devices with modified system fonts?

Tags: ios, fonts

As you knnow, many users will change default system fonts after they jailbreak their iOS devices. But this may cause the text height calculated wrong and make the UI of iOS app looks ugly. Because the font name of that font is the same as system default, but it's totally different font. So when call below method:

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font
```

it may return incorrect size.

So, I just want to know how to calculate the actual text height of specific font. Thanks.

Comment: They're modifying the system. They should expect bad stuff to happen. IMO, not your problem.

Comment: `sizeWithFont:` is deprecated in iOS 7, you should try to use `sizeWithAttributes:` 
I don't know if it fixes the problem with jailbreak fonts, but it is worth the try.

Comment: @VaaChar `sizeWithAttributes:` act just the same as `sizeWithFont:`. Thanks.

Comment: @rdurand I do think so, but just trying to make my app looks the same on every device. Any way, thanks.

Comment: @celtavonce : I completely understand. Your best option is to use custom fonts and forget about the system font. I believe this will solve the problem, and your app will look nice even on a jailbroken device. Because even if, **if** you find a way to get a correct size that solves your layout issues, the custom fonts people use will make your app ugly.